# FBReaderJ crashes with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library LineBreak not found

Tags: android

I have downloaded FBReaderJ project from gitHub and struggling to make it run on my emulator.I get the folloing error in my logcat:

04-27 16:40:36.750: WARN/dalvikvm(200): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lorg/vimgadgets/linebreak/LineBreaker;.
04-27 16:40:36.750: WARN/dalvikvm(200): threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-27 16:40:36.801: WARN/System.err(200): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-27 16:40:36.801: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.zlibrary.text.view.ZLTextParagraphCursor.fill(ZLTextParagraphCursor.java:195)
04-27 16:40:36.801: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.zlibrary.text.view.ZLTextParagraphCursor.(ZLTextParagraphCursor.java:178)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.zlibrary.text.view.ZLTextParagraphCursor.cursor(ZLTextParagraphCursor.java:184)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.zlibrary.text.view.ZLTextView.setModel(ZLTextView.java:74)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBView.setModel(FBView.java:47)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp.openBookInternal(FBReaderApp.java:231)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.fbreader.fbreader.FBReaderApp$1.run(FBReaderApp.java:145)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.geometerplus.android.util.UIUtil$2.run(UIUtil.java:78)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library LineBreak not found
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
04-27 16:40:36.809: WARN/System.err(200):     at org.vimgadgets.linebreak.LineBreaker.(LineBreaker.java:5)

I have installed and successfully compiled the NDK.
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it shows that u are not having JNI folder in your project & u may not have the native library file("example.so") of it. (.so) is the extension of library file. to build this .so file u must need android NDK & a software called "cygwin" which helps to build the native file from JNI folder

Comment: @hotveryspicy Thanks for your answer. I implemented the all steps for NDK and i missed to reload the project into workspace and now its working fine.

Comment: ohh really, its a hearty pleasure best of Luck